# Why does this work for the NYT's World RSS but not for the Science one? (XPath, Java)

Tags: java, xpath, rss

This piece of Java code prints the title, link and publication date of every item from the NYT's World RSS. But for the NYT's Science RSS it doesn't print the link field. What is happening here?

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = builder.parse( direccion );
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/rss/channel/item");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nl.item(i);

    Node nodoTitulo = (Node) xpath.evaluate("title", node, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(nodoTitulo.getTextContent());

    Node nodoLink = (Node) xpath.evaluate("link", node, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(nodoLink.getTextContent());

    Node nodoFecha = (Node) xpath.evaluate("pubDate", node, XPathConstants.NODE);
    System.out.println(nodoFecha.getTextContent());
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I think it's a namespacing issue.  It's picking up the `<atom:link.../>` node before the `<link.../>` node.  In the science RSS, this comes first, in the world RSS, it comes later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `namespace` issue.

In the science RSS, you have

```
<atom:link href="http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/19/business/new-wave-of-adept-robots-is-changing-global-industry.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss" rel="standout"/>
<title>The iEconomy: New Wave of Deft Robots Is Changing Global Industry</title>
<link>http://feeds.nytimes.com/click.phdo?i=5861b5e3f6b66da6ca12beab1e5d8729</link>
```

In the world RSS, you have

```
<title>Syrian Rebels Claim to Have Brought Down a Jet</title>
<link>http://feeds.nytimes.com/click.phdo?i=314bd32f9d6141a500e76e3076c489c9</link>
.
.
.
<atom:link rel="standout" href="http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/14/world/middleeast/syrian-rebels-claim-to-have-brought-down-a-jet.html?partner=rss&amp;emc=rss"/>
```

Your code is picking up the `<atmoic:link>` node first.

Add:

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

After you create the factory and before you create the builder and you should now be getting the link

```
title = The iEconomy: New Wave of Deft Robots Is Changing Global Industry
link = http://feeds.nytimes.com/click.phdo?i=5861b5e3f6b66da6ca12beab1e5d8729
pubDate = Sun, 19 Aug 2012 21:26:33 GMT
```

And if you're really interested, you can have a read of [this](http://blog.davber.com/2006/09/17/xpath-with-namespaces-in-java/) for some more info